# confusing SSL certificate error - is port number allowed?

Tags: ios, ssl, internet-explorer-9, ssl-certificate

I am getting an error accessing our site with iOS safari, and I managed to find the error using the remote debugger on safari, which seems to say the SSL certificate is wrong, but the error is pretty confusing:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. 
You might be connecting to a server https://myserver.mydomain.com:36000/something that is pretending to be “myserver.mydomain.com” 
which could put your confidential information at risk. (connect, line 0)
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be? My best guess is the port on the url might be the problem, but as far as I know it should be valid.

I don't get this error on any other browser I've tested, although there is an error on IE9 which I think might be the same problem, as it seems to be triggered when hitting the same url, but that has no useful information:

```
Error: Access is denied.
undefined
```

(I don't get this error on IE9 with the "Access data sources across domains" option enabled, so it might not be related)

Any clues how to debug this?

Comment: The "CommonName" of your SLL certificate is likely set to the web address without the port number. The web address your client will connect to must be *exactly* the same as the "CommonName" attribute in the certificate. E.g., if CN equals "myserver.mydomain.com" and you connect via "www.myserver.mydomain.com" or "myserver.mydomain.com:1234", it fails.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper That's my best guess, but as far as I know, it should work with every port on the domain, shouldn't it? A co-worker found [this link](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=693) that says it should, and they actually say setting "CommonName" to the port would give an error. Can someone confirm what it is supposed to work like?

Comment: I can't verify this assertion from your link at the moment, but I'll try to investigate this later (the relevant RFC is RFC 2459). As an alternative or workaround, you might "bind" additionally identities (IP addresses) with the "Subject Alternative Name" attribute specified in your server certificate. Please see [RFC 2459](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2459). Also, please note that this stuff is "critical regarding security" - so please don't change things when you don't know about the consequences ;)

Comment: Certs don't take ports into account, only the host name, so the port isn't your problem. You're going to need to post details of the public part of the cert and the fqdn you are using to connect to it for more help.

Comment: @blowdart [Here are some details of the certificate](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=blackjack-attack-static.gamevy.com&hideResults=on), the actual url that is throwing errors is rohrpost-server.gamevy.com:36000 (and they use the same cert), but this tool doesn't like the 36000 port. Does that help? Any more info I should post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the CA certificate in your certificate chain. Make sure it it's in the file AND in the correct order.

Comment: we needed to pass the intermediate cert to express, like here (the "ca" bit): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/K514giTPvT0